# Jade Conditional Menu

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a nav menu that I only want to show on the main page and not on my /contact page. Is there a conditional way of doing this so that when someone is on the contact page, i.e. localhost:8080/contact, that the top nav will only show 'x' links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make Jade aware of the URL path first, for it to use it in the condition.

```
app.use(function setLocals(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.path = req.path;
    // 'path' variable is now available in your Jade Template
    next();
});
```

Now you can use `path` in your Jade Template

```
.menu
    .link This will appear everywhere 
    if(path!='/contact')
        .link This won't appear on /contact
```